# Complete user profile after social public registration

Tags: registration, authentication, plugin-social-login

I use [Dukt plugins](https://dukt.net/) (-[oauth](https://dukt.net/craft/oauth) and -[social](https://dukt.net/craft/social)) for public front-end registration. I would like complete user profile after registration (e.g. license agreement checkbox).

How is it possible to accomplish this?

I would like intercept social callback after authentication and show a custom page.... I suppose OnBeforeSave event is not useful for this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via https://dukt.net/craft/social/docs/templating/craft.social#getLoginUrl you may give up a page like `{ redirect: 'user/finish' }` on which you could check if a user agreed to the license agreement and if they have redirect them to the regular page.

Here is an example profile edit page that might be useful https://github.com/dukt/social-demo/blob/master/craft/templates/social/profile.html

Comment: Thanks Maarten, so every login, I redirect users to a specific page for checking profile completeness; if it isn't "completed", user agree license otherwise he will be automatically redirected to homepage (or similar)... is it correct?

Comment: Yeah however I'm not sure about preventing the user from visiting other sections of the website. Perhaps you could change the user group once they agree to the terms so they can visit other pages.